# Creating artifacts in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have been tasked with looking into using Jenkins as a build server. So far I have managed to pull a project from git, restore the Nuget packages, build the project and run the unit tests. However I am struggling to find out how to generate the artifact.

The way the business would like to have the build server generate a zip file to a directory on the build server or a remote server for the systems team then to pick up and deploy to the relevant location. E.g. given a windows service project the built bin directory would be zipped up and put in the relevant artifact directory.

I thought that in order to do this I add an `archive the artifacts` post-build action. However I am getting the below error:

```
‘Watchdog.WinService.Monitor/bin/Release/*.zip’ doesn’t match anything: 
‘Watchdog.WinService.Monitor’ exists but not 
‘Watchdog.WinService.Monitor/bin/Release/*.zip’
```

If I look in the workspace for this project I can browse to the bin directory and see all the files so I unsure what I have done wrong.

Can someone please let me know if what I am trying to accomplish is possible, and also if our approach to using Jenkins is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to create the artifact using the archive artifatcs step. 
But the step is to collect artifacts and show them on the job page.
That means you need to create the artifact first e.g. using a shell or batch script.

You can combine this with the [Flexible Publish Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin).

When you select this as post build step you can create a conditional action that runs the artifact archive task and as condition executes the script that creates the zip file.

So if that fails the task won't be executed. Also it may causes your job to 'fail' but that may not be the case in your job.